# ng-repeat, show item every nth time for repeated blocks

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-if="need something here i.e. $index = ...">
    </div>
    ..data..
</div>
```

So I have the above pattern. The `items` list is fetched from the server. On pressing the "load more" button, second page is pulled. One page contains 8 items by default. But this can be specified by the user so it can be set to a different value (9,10 for example). Taking the default value 8, the $index values would look like the following for page 1:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

If more pages are pulled:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
... and so one
```

I want to apply `ng-if` on something so that it is shown every 4th item on the block. It therefore follows the formula: `3 + i*(total_items_per_page)`. So for a list when `total_items_per_page = 8`

```
0
1
2
3
  <--- here
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
  <--- here
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
  <--- here
20
21
... and so one
```

I tried `$index == (page_number-1)*total_items_per_page + 3`, this works but obviously removes items above the current page when load more is pressed. Looking to solve this or for a better solution.

Edit: I am also trying to avoid predefined arrays to make this as flexible as possible for variable `total_items_per_page` values

Comment: Why do not to use pagination?

Comment: Expected results/objective is not very clear....probably why you don't already have an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this, it's correct for all cases, 4, 12, 20, 28 ...:

```
ng-if="($index+8) % 8 == 4"
```